# Trying to seed Faker in a Laravel factory produces PHP error 'Undefined offset'

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I have the following Factory in Laravel 5.5

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Student::class, function (Faker $faker, $form) {
    //$faker->addProvider(new \Faker\Provider\SIMS($faker));
    $faker->seed(1234);
    echo $faker->name;
});
```

When I run `php artisan db:seed` I get the error `In Base.php line 194: Undefined offset: -57` with the offset being different depending on what value I use for `$faker->seed(1234)`. Leaving this line out of the factory causes the seed to run successfully but obviously I end up with different data each time, hence the need to seed Faker.

Base.php is part of Faker and looks like this

```
public static function randomElements(array $array = array('a', 'b', 'c'), $count = 1, $allowDuplicates = false)
    {
        $allKeys = array_keys($array);
        $numKeys = count($allKeys);

        if (!$allowDuplicates && $numKeys < $count) {
            throw new \LengthException(sprintf('Cannot get %d elements, only %d in array', $count, $numKeys));
        }

        $highKey = $numKeys - 1;
        $keys = $elements = array();
        $numElements = 0;

        while ($numElements < $count) {
            $num = mt_rand(0, $highKey);

            if (!$allowDuplicates) {
                if (isset($keys[$num])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $keys[$num] = true;
            }

            $elements[] = $array[$allKeys[$num]];  //THIS IS LINE 194.
            $numElements++;
        }

        return $elements;
    }
```

I have not modified it since installing Laravel.

The Student Factory is being called by the Form Factory like so

```
factory(App\Form::class, $numberOfStudentsInForm)->create()->each(function ($form)
        {
            echo ("Seeding Students of Form $form->name\r\n");
            factory(App\Student::class, 30)->create(['form_id'=>$form]);
        });
```

The Student Model looks like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Student extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = "admission_number";
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = "string";

    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form');
    }

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Grade');
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        return ($this->grades()->delete() && parent::delete());
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: does new \Faker\Provider\SIMS($faker) create a datetime ?

Comment: @mahdi-younesi No, but I can see why you asked, I will remove that line as it is not relevant to my question and the problem exists whether that line is in there or not.

Comment: You should probably return something like an array of fields for your Student::class

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks, I do in my actual code. I just wanted to post the minimum amount of code here to recreate the issue. It's worth noting that I get the same problem when trying to seed Faker in other factories too so I don't think it's a problem with this factory.

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with `Base.php` but either with your `Student::class` or your seeder file. How do you call the factory?

Comment: @kerbholz I am calling the factory from another factory. I'll add that to the question.